# Simple Craft htaccess Help

Tags: htaccess

I have a Craft site where I need to redirect any traffic to www (including dev.lakesideohio.com). The rule seems to be working but for some reason the url gets changed to using index.php with query string which I am not using.

For example https://mysite.com/news goes to https://www.mysite.com/index.php?p=news/ instead of https://www.mysite.com/news.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: [Removing “index.php” from URLs](https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php)

Comment: Perfect. 'omitScriptNameInUrls' was commented out in my multi environment config. Thanks Andrew!